# try-with-resources or close() dilemma

Tags: java, exception

I have a function that can throw IOException, so I don't catch the exception internally. however I've some resources to close. Is it correct to do in that way, using try-with-resource (without any catch block):

```
public void workOnFiles() throws IOException {

    try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("bau.txt");) {
        // Do some stuff
    }       
}
```

Or I should do something like that:

```
public void workOnFiles() throws IOException {

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("bau.txt");
    // Do some stuff
    fis.close();    
}
```

Comment: The second one would be acceptable if the close call was in a finally block.

Answer (score 5):

In 2nd one, if the exception is thrown, your `fis` won't be closed. An option is to enclose the statement that can throw th exception in a `try` block, and close the `fis` in a `finally` block.

But, since you are already on *Java 7*, you should use [try-with-resource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Answer (score 0):

try-with-resources always closes`(Closeable resources)` the resource whether exception raises or not`(Work only java7 onwards)`.

Where as your second code do not close resource if exception raises.
So you can use `try-with-resources` if you are using `java7` or else edit your code with `try` and `finally` block.

`finally block guarantees execution irrespective of exception raises or not`

Answer (score 0):

If you are keen on using the second method , then close the resource in `finally` block.

```
public void workOnFiles() throws IOException {
   FileInputStream fis = null;
   try {
     fis = new FileInputStream("bau.txt");
   // Do some stuff
   }
   finally  {
     try {
      fis.close(); 
     }
     catch(Exception e) {
      //logger.error(e);
      // e.printStackTrace();
     }   
}
```

Comment: OP is using Java7's try with resource feature.  A try with resource block excepts `Closeable`mplementation and incase of exception they get closed automatically

Comment: Yes he mentioned that , just in case if he needs to use the second method i showed him the way !